# Map host physical address to kvm guest

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, linux-device-driver, qemu, kvm

I have a physical address in my host (its a pci bar address), and I want a driver in my kvm guest to access that address.
Whats the best way i can do such a thing?

If it was a linux process and not a kvm guest, I would just open and mmap /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/resource0 in my process, is there something equivalent I can do in a kvm guest?

Answer (score 2):

All operations in the guest use Guest Virtual Addresses or Guest Physical Addresses. The translation to Host Physical Address may be done with Shadow Page Tables or Second Level Address Translation (like EPT) depending on your hardware and configuration. This implies that Host Physical Addresses have no meaning in the VM, or at least they can't be used directly without some work involving the cooperation of the hypervisor.

I don't know much about it, but you may want to look into the implementation of PCI Passthrough for network devices.